# Testing existence of a routine fails while building module

Tags: perl, testing, module, test-more

I'm currently working on building a library to implement in Project Euler puzzles. I've gotten to the point of building tests but at some point my tests fail. Everything imports okay but as soon is I test for the existence of a subroutine my newly created test fails. I initially started Test::More but to simplify things I switched to Test::Simple. With each run, even after simplifying to less complex functions for testing, I get the same error output. Is there some error in my code that I'm overlooking or is there some aspect of my system or environment that is affecting this?

NOTE: I have reviewed Test::Tutorial several times in addition to Test::Simple and Test::More docs. I also made sure to review the Perl Docs for the relevant functions (defined and exists).   Using Perl 5.18.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's the output:

```
    t/00-load.t ....... 1/? # Testing EulerUtils 0.01, Perl 5.018002, /usr/bin/perl
    t/00-load.t ....... ok   
    t/Qual.t .......... 1/2 
    #   Failed test 'isEven() exists'
    #   at t/Qual.t line 8.
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
    t/Qual.t .......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    Failed 1/2 subtests 
    t/boilerplate.t ... ok   
    t/manifest.t ...... skipped: Author tests not required for installation
    t/pod-coverage.t .. ok   
    t/pod.t ........... ok   

    Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    t/Qual.t        (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  2
      Non-zero exit status: 1
    Files=6, Tests=10,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.01 sys +  0.23 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.34        CPU)
    Result: FAIL
    Failed 1/6 test programs. 1/10 subtests failed.
```

Nothing object oriented, by the way...at least so far. I made a dummy test too, which explains the 2 subtests.

The test itself (updated to make the library location explicit):

```
use v5.18.2;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use FindBin;

use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";
use Test::Simple tests => 1;

use Qual;
ok( defined(&isEven), 'isEven() exists' );
```

The subroutine from the module itself, made with module-starter:

```
...
sub isEven {
        my $n = shift;
        return 1 if ($n % 2 == 0);
}
...
```

Let me know if there's something needed.

Comment: how about the top of Qual.pm?  Does it in fact export isEven?  (if you don't know what that means, you should probably read http://p3rl.org/Exporter)

Comment: Yes, I know what that means...and that was it. -_-

Comment: A minimal `Qual` would have been helpful; as in many cases, preparing that would have solved the issue probably ;-) Sometimes you just have to focus on the essential details like default exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that test is failing, you apparently aren't exporting isEven from Qual.  Assuming you are using Exporter, if it is in `@EXPORT_OK`, you need to explicitly request it in Qual.t:

```
use Qual 'isEven';
```

or move it to `@EXPORT` (though nowadays it is recommended that *nothing* be exported by default).